# Get MS Excel Properties, Python 3.6

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas

I want to find "Last Modified" Date from Excel File.

Script

```
os.stat(Excel_File_Path).st_ctime
```

gives locally created time, but I want to fetch Excel File "Last Modified", which is available in Excel Properties, I use Excel 2013, here if I select "File" it will show Excel Properties like attached image[image]

Original File: http://www.jisf.or.jp/en/statistics/production/documents/product_s_1902.xls

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: @UditHariVashisht, Windows 10

Answer (score 1):

You can get the modified time by using 
`import os`
`os.path.getmtime(path_to_file)`

More details [here.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.getmtime)

Comment: It will give "Return the time of last modification of path", but I want to fetch the Data modified, I am not doing any modification in the file locally, I just download file and want to find when it was updated in source.

Comment: Please download the link given above and check os.path.getmtime(path_to_file), it will give locally created date. Then Open File and click "File" option, there Last Modified will be different.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible as per the dcoumentation

The “ctime” as reported by the operating system. On some systems (like Unix) is the time of the last metadata change, and, on others (like Windows), is the creation time (see platform documentation for details).